# pip3 install with "--extra-index-url" cannot reolve the dependencies

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am attempting to install tensorflow on an NVidia jetson platofrm using the instructions in the [Nvidia Docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html). I initially run the follwong command to install the dependencies as described in the docs:

```
pip3 install -U numpy grpcio absl-py py-cpuinfo psutil portpicker six mock requests gast h5py astor termcolor protobuf keras-applications keras-preprocessing wrapt google-pasta
```

After that I run the command to install the specific version of tensorflow-gpu from NVidia using "--extra-index-url" and the URL provided:

```
pip3 install --extra-index-url https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v42 tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1+nv19.5
```

Every time I run this it throws an error which I believe is because appears to check for one of the dependencies at the NVidia URL (where they obviously don't reside). I reinstall the dependencies, or install the specific one that was mentioned in the error and when I run the command again it will throw an error for another (seemingly random) dependency. Example error message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v42/wheel/
```

Comment: Can you run `pip3 --version` and `pip3 install -vvv --extra-index-url https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v42 tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1+nv19.5` and add the output of both commands to the question?